# MemoryStream Disposed after using Workbook.Save() method OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have been messing with this for hours to no avail. I am trying to copy an excel file, add a new sheet to it, put the file in a MemoryStream and then return the stream.

Here is the code:

```
public Stream ProcessDocument()
{
        var resultStream = new MemoryStream();

        string sourcePath = "path\\to\\file";
        string destinationPath = "path\\to\\file";

        CopyFile(destinationPath, sourcePath);

        var copiedFile = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(destinationPath, true);
        var fileWithSheets = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("path\\to\\file", false);

        AddCopyOfSheet(fileWithSheets.WorkbookPart, copiedFile.WorkbookPart, "foo");

        using(var stream = new MemoryStream()){
                copiedFile.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                stream.CopyTo(resultsStream);
        }

        return resultsStream;
}

public void CopyFile(string outputFullFilePath, string inputFileFullPath)
{       
        int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputFullFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(inputFileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileStream.SetLength(fs.Length);
            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(bytes, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
            {
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            fs.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }

public static void AddCopyOfSheet(WorkbookPart sourceDocument, WorkbookPart destinationDocument, string sheetName)
{
        WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorkSheetPart(sourceDocument, sheetName);
        destinationDocument.AddPart(sourceSheetPart);
}

public static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
{
        string id = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(x => x.Name.Value.Contains(sheetName)).Id
        return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(id);
}
```

The issue seems to arise from  `copiedFile.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream)`.

After this is ran, I get an error saying that there was an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'. The file copies fine and adding the sheet seems to also be working.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using .Save() without stream as a parameter. It does nothing.
2. Using two different streams (hence the resultStream jank left in this code)
3. Going pure OpenXML and copying the WorkbookParts to a stream directly. Tested with a plain text excel and was fine, but it breaks the desired file because it has some advanced formatting that does not seem to work well with OpenXML. I am open to refactoring if someone knows how I could work around this, though.

What I haven't tried:

1. Creating ANOTHER copy of the copy and using the SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, type) method. I have a feeling this would work but it seems like an awful and slow solution.
2. Updating OpenXML. I am currently on 2.5.

Any feedback or ideas are hugely appreciated. Thank you!

PS: My dev box is airgapped so I had to hand write this code over. Sorry if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `copiedFile.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream);` disposes of the stream by default. The workaround to this was to make a MemoryStream class that overloads its ability to be disposed, like so:

```
public class DisposeLockableMemoryStream : MemoryStream
{
   public DisposeLockableMemoryStream(bool allowDispose)
   {
       AllowDispose = allowDispose;
   }

   public bool AllowDispose { get; set; }

   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (!AllowDispose)
           return;

       base.Dispose(disposing);
   }
}
```

All you need to do is make sure you `stream.AllowDispose = true` and then dispose of it once you're done.

Now, this didn't really fix my code because it turns out that `.Save()` *only tracks changes made to the document, not the entire thing!!!*. Basically, this library is hot garbage and I regret signing up for this story to begin with.

For more information, see a [post I made on r/csharp](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/r6gn9w/memorystream_disposed_after_using_workbooksave/).

Answer (score 0):

For me it turns out that right method for saving is `spreadsheetDocument.Dispose()` and not `WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream)`.

```
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart!.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

    Create sheets...

    spreadsheetDocument.Dispose();
```

It's strange, but this keep my content in memory and I can use it later.